# Probabilistic Combinatorics - Need an equation to model the distribution of marbles inside buckets

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

I'm trying to come up with an equation to model a computational networking problem but to do that, I need to get an equation to model a subproblem.
I've simplified this subproblem down to marbles and buckets so that it's easier to think about.
I think this falls in the field of probabilistic combinatorics, but I'm not sure.

Here is the problem:

Assume that I have **m** number of marbles and **b** number of buckets.

The experiment is this:

I start with **m** marbles on one side and **b** buckets on the other.
Then, I randomly place each marble inside a bucket, and when no marbles remain, I count the number of buckets which are not empty.

What will be the average number of non-empty buckets per experiment over the course of **n** experiments where **n** approaches infinity.

I need an equation in which I can substitute any value for **m** and **b** and it will give me the answer as a number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The average number can be interpreted as $\mathbb EX$ where $X$ denotes the number of non-empty buckets after one experiment.

For $i=1,\dots,b$ let $X_{i}$ take value $1$ if 
bucket $i$ is not empty and let it take value $0$ otherwise.

Then $X=X_{1}+\cdots+X_{b}$ and:

$$\mathbb{E}X=\mathbb{E}\left(X_{1}+\cdots+X_{b}\right)=\mathbb{E}X_{1}+\cdots+\mathbb{E}X_{b}=b\mathbb{E}X_{1}$$
The last equation because each bucket has the same probability of
ending up non-empty. It remains to find $\mathbb{E}X_{1}=\mathbb{P}\left(X_{1}=1\right)$.

Bucket $1$  has a probability of $\left(1-\frac{1}{b}\right)^{m}$
of staying empty, so we end up with:

$$\mathbb{E}X=b\left[1-\left(1-\frac{1}{b}\right)^{m}\right]$$